# XBOX 360 Arcade multiple USB flash drives

Tags: xbox-360

Recently I grabbed rather old [XBOX 360 Arcade](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0029MAXS6) for my son who wanted to play Minecraft that is [not yet](http://www.gottabemobile.com/2013/08/20/minecraft-coming-to-ps4-ps3/) available on PS3. This console doesn't have much internal storage and after resetting and applying latest updates, only about 24 MB is left. I read that I can either add external HDD or [USB flash drive](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-360/accessories/usb-flash-drive) to it. I have couple of spare USB drives and one of them actually worked. It is small (4GB) and I am planning to add more. This is my secondary console so I don't want to spend too much money on it. Few questions...

- I see 3 USB ports so can I put three USB flash drives of 32GB each if I wanted to?
- I am thinking about not getting HDD storage at all as it is more expensive and very specific to XBOX. USB flash drives are multi-purpose and I could use those elsewhere after the console dies or I don't want to use it anymore. Any downside to this?
- I would like to buy games from live account instead of on physical disks. The table in the [link](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-360/accessories/usb-flash-drive) seems to indicate that it is supported but I wanted to confirm as some older articles say otherwise. It seems like this support was added much later after the console was released.
- Can the installed game be moved from one flash drive to another?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use multiple USB flash drives simultaneously.

From my experience the XBox is a bit finicky about USB flash drives though. The internal hard drive is much more reliable. YMMV  Also all three USB flash drives will mount with the same name, so it will be difficult to differentiate them when you have to choose the storage device.